# How can i resolve "unknown flag: --progress" error when ddev start?

Tags: php, docker, drupal, ddev, drupal-9

I'm trying to start my drupal 9 site with ddev and I am having an error

> unknown flag: --progress

The result when I type ddev version:

```
 ITEM             VALUE                                   
 DDEV version     v1.22.0                                 
 architecture     amd64                                   
 db               ddev/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.22.0 
 ddev-ssh-agent   ddev/ddev-ssh-agent:v1.22.0             
 docker           24.0.5                                  
 docker-compose   v2.10.2                                 
 docker-platform  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS                      
 mutagen          0.17.2                                  
 os               linux                                   
 router           traefik:v2.10                           
 web              ddev/ddev-webserver:v1.22.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overridden the `docker-compose` required by DDEV in your ~/.ddev/global_config.yaml - the version you have set does not have the `--progress` option.

To fix, please edit your ~/.ddev/global_config.yaml and delete the lines `required_docker_compose_version` and `use-docker-compose-from-path`.

You can also do the same thing with:

```
 ddev config global --required-docker-compose-version="" --use-docker-compose-from-path=false
```

(Those configuration options are only there for specialized testing and for the upstream docker-compose tests to use.)